# Bitbucket pushing Git Repository not Working

Tags: android, git, bitbucket

I am working in Android Studio and I recently created a local git repository and I trying to push them to bitbucket in an empty Repository. So I followed the instructions (I'm working on Linux):

```
$ cd /path/to/my/repo
$ git remote add origin https://tdmsoares@bitbucket.org/tdmsoares/stingy-money.git
$ git push -u origin --all
```

When I type this last line, I receive this message:

```
$ git push -u --all
refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

I found it strange because because when working in Android Studio, it shows me I am in a Master Branch.

Maybe it can be a rookie mistake (I am beginner at Git). I searched for this problem and what I found didn't solve this issue.

Comment: try git push origin master

Comment: I tried this, but I receive this message: 
`git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://tdmsoares@bitbucket.org/tdmsoares/stingy-money.git'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push depends on your git version.

Prior to GIT2.x the push used the `simple` value while starting at GIT2.X it has changed to `matching` so again depend on your git version looks like you have to use the following lines:

```
# Update your local copy
git fetch --all -- prune

# push your changes 
git push origin master
```

### What does the error means:

It simply means that you have not committed anything. add your content and then commit & push.

Comment: When I type `git push origin master`, I get this message: `error: src refspec master does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to 'https://tdmsoares@bitbucket.org/tdmsoares/stingy-money.git'`

Comment: saw your comment above, it due to the fact that you did not commit any new stuff

Comment: Thanks! I missed a simple thing like this... All I have done was Adding files to Repository, not committing them... Now it worked!